# Saving TimeSpan into SQL Server 2012 as a Time column with ServiceStack OrmLite and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

I have a `Time(7)` column in a database table, and I want to save a `TimeSpan` using C# and ORMLite as Object Relational Mapper. While performing this action I get this exception

> Operand type clash: bigint is incompatible with time

This is my server stack trace;

```
[UpdateJobFrequency: 11/07/2015 5:43:39 AM]:
[REQUEST: {JobFrequency:{Id:0,JobId:3,FrequencyId:2,InstanceOfFrequency:1,Time:PT1H,WeekNumber:0}}]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Operand type clash: bigint is incompatible with time
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadCommandExtensions.LongScalar(IDbCommand dbCmd)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteResultsFilterExtensions.ExecLongScalar(IDbCommand dbCmd, String sql)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteDialectProviderBase`1.InsertAndGetLastInsertId[T](IDbCommand dbCmd)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions.Insert[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, T obj, Boolean selectIdentity)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteApi.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.<Insert>b__3(IDbCommand dbCmd)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExpressionsApi.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteApi.Insert[T](IDbConnection dbConn, T obj, Boolean selectIdentity)
   at JobRepositoryBase.<Create>d__a`1.MoveNext() in c:\dev\RepositoryBase.cs:line 89
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Job.WebAppHost.Service.JobFrequencyService.<Post>d__6.MoveNext() in c:\dev\JobFrequencyService.cs:line 30
```

I am passing `01:00:00` as `TimeSpan` value from the interface but it is showing as `Time: PT1H` in the object at server side.

Also, I have read in one of the stack overflow questionnaire  that ADO.Net `TimeSpan` is mapped to SQL Server `Time(7)`. And I believe that servicestack ORMLite is built upon ADO.Net. However, in this case I am facing this exception.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @marc_s can you please suggest me any solution?

Comment: No, sorry - but I believe it's a problem of ORMLite - using "raw" ADO.NET, this mapping from .NET `TimeSpan` to SQL Server `time(7)` definitely works. ORMLite seems to convert your timespan to a `bigint` and that isn't compatible with `time(7)` - try to raise the issue in the ORMlite support forums or notify the author

Comment: @mythz Being lead contributor in servicestack I think you may be the right person to tag in this question, would you be able to help me with this?

Comment: @Learner OrmLite stores TimeSpan in a bigint by design as it's the only data type that works reliably in all supported RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to urgency, I had to do a workaround for the problem, I had to change the data type of my table to BigInt. So, what ORMLite is doing is mapping the BigInt as TimeSpan and vice versa - [Github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteDialectProviderBase.cs), now I can store and retrieve this field without any problem.

But still I believe this is not a perfect solution as in my case I am developing database from scratch, but in a case where someone has to use the existing database, this workaround fails.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, there is now a working solution for utilizing MS SQL's 'Time' column with ORMLite, mapped to TimeSpan type in C#. Simply place the code below anywhere within your C# application:

```
    //Enable ORMLite to suppot MS SQL 'Time' column
    //Based on https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/wiki/OrmLite-Type-Converters
    SqlServerDialect.Provider.RegisterConverter<TimeSpan>(new ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.SqlServerTimeConverter
    {
        Precision = 7
    });
```